# How to reverse proxy to different places depending on subdomain in Nginx?

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, subdomain

I have multiple subdomains, all pointing to one machine, and one IP address. On this machine, I want to have nginx acting as a reverse proxy, and depending on which subdomain was used to access the machine, I want it to reverse proxy to a different server. All the examples I've seen of using nginx as a reverse proxy use `location`, but as I understand that only works for the path, not for different subdomains. How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: This might be a bit too broad. Can you post more about what you've tried already?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Unless I completely misread your question: You simply set up server blocks  for each sub-domain and the define the correct reverse proxy for the root of that subdomain i.e. something along the lines of:

```
 server {
        server_name subdomain1.example.com;
        location / {
            proxy_pass       http://hostname1:port1;
        }
 }
 server {
        server_name subdomain2.example.com;
        location / {
            proxy_pass       http://hostname2:port2;
        }
 }
```

Comment: Sorry for late response, but I got it working!

Comment: This is magic, and you're a wizard!

Comment: Is it possible to access those addresses over https? I have an A-RECORD for subdomain.example.com. Do I need some more configuration to enable ssl access?

Comment: Now if I hit the IP address for `example.com`, the requests are sent to the first server. How can prevent that?

Comment: @elano7 You need to add `listen 443 ssl;`, along with `ssl_certificate` and `ssl_certificate_key` directives, pointing to the certificate and the private key respectively.

Answer (score 4):

Pretty much the same way.

```
location /foo {
    rewrite ^/foo(.+)$ /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://foo;
}

location /bar {
    rewrite ^/bar(.+)$ /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://bar;
}
```

Comment: How does this work for subdomains though? The location and regex seem to be specifically for a path.

Comment: To be honest, seems like I've clearly misread the question. :)

Comment: Hehe. We've all been there. 